# Regarding the temporary generation of token in Agora.io

Tags: c#, video-streaming, agora.io, videocall, agora

Is there any solution for the regeneration of the temporary token in unity. Is there any way to get the permanent token for the agora and no need to go on agora console and generate the token again and again

Is there any solution for the regeneration of the temporary token in unity. Is there any way to get the permanent token for the agora and no need to go on agora console and generate the token again and again

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The “_What did you try and what were you expecting_” section in the [ask wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/askwizard) is not meant for you to copy/paste your question again. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to accurately display what you have attempted so far. If you have any code, please add a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

The Agora temp token is required for any user. There is no permanent token. Agora makes it easier to test by letting you make a free token in their console but your final solution will require you to set up a token server. I put my on Railway and used the sample code from the Agora SDK and managed to set it up in half a day. There is no alternative though except for using the tokens.